# Bevy Game Engine 0.11.2 despawn function expectes a different parameter type

Tags: rust, bevy

I am trying to despawn some entitys I spawned using the commands.spawn() function but it is expecting a different type parament for the commands.entity().despawn function. Here is my code:

```
fn despawn(
    commands: Commands,
    player: Query<&Player>,
) {
    commands.entity(player).despawn()
}
```

this code gives me the error: expected struct `bevy::prelude::Entity`
found struct `bevy::prelude::Query<'_, '_, &Player>` How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Commands::entity`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.11.2/bevy/ecs/system/struct.Commands.html#method.entity) requires the [`Entity`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.11.2/bevy/ecs/entity/struct.Entity.html), which is an unique identifier for an entity and associated components. To get the `Entity` from a `Query`, include it in the parameters like [shown here](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.11.2/bevy/ecs/system/struct.Query.html#entity-identifier-access):

```
player: Query<(Entity, &Player)>,
```

---

A `Query` is an iterator-adjacent structure that yields the entities and components you're querying for. So your query can potentially yield multiple players if multiple entities have the `Player` component. So you can handle multiple of them like so:

```
fn despawn(
    mut commands: Commands,
    players: Query<(Entity, &Player)>,
) {
    for (player_id, _player) in players.iter() {
        commands.entity(player_id).despawn();
    }
}
```

Or if only one entity is expected, you can use `get_single`:

```
if let Ok((player_id, _player)) = players.get_single() {
    commands.entity(player_id).despawn();
}
```

---

Lastly, if you don't actually need to access the `Player` component and have just included it to filter what entites are despawned, use a [`With`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.11.2/bevy/ecs/query/struct.With.html) filter instead. See [disjoint queries](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.11.2/bevy/ecs/system/struct.Query.html#disjoint-queries) for an example. It would look like this:

```
fn despawn(
    mut commands: Commands,
    players: Query<Entity, With<Player>>,
) {
    for player_id in players.iter() {
        commands.entity(player_id).despawn();
    }
}
```